# typeof(T) vs <T>

Tags: .net, generics, typeof

In .NET there seem to be two ways to pass a type to a method or class. The first is through generics, in which we pass a type as a special parameter.

Such as:

```
var list = new List<MyClass>();
```

The other way is to explicity use the `typeof` operator such as:

```
var pe = Expression.ParameterExpression(typeof(MyClass), "myinstance");
```

My question is regarding the discrepancy in a uniform interface to methods that require a type parameter. Why can't the above statement be done as follows?:

```
var pe = Expression.ParameterExpression<MyClass>("myinstance");
```

Is it because there are two semantic differences required in how the compiler behaves? When a generic parameter is processed by the compiler does it simply perform substitution ala lambda calculus? Whereas the `typeof` style methods require an actual instance of the `Type` class to infer attributes and properties from?

Thank you.

Comment: Those "special parameters" are called type parameters, just so you know :)

Comment: Imagine the wide expanse of the Pacific Ocean.  Type is in Japan, T is in California.  T gets to Hawaii a thousand times quicker.

Comment: @Richard. I'm aware. I dont know why I expressed it that way. Generics are academically referred to as Parametric Polymorphism, so a type parameter immediately follows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first method allows you to calculate the required type at runtime.

```
Expression.ParameterExpression(CalculateType(), "myinstance");
```

Personally I wouldn't mind seeing an overload which would definitely make code with a type defined at compile time much cleaner.

Comment: What an obvious reason! I can't believe I overlooked that! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this method signature.

```
public object MyGetInstanceOfType(Type theType)
```

While an instance of the appropriate type might be returned, the compiler has no way to verify it... theType isn't known until runtime (well after the compiler is involved).

Contrast with this:

```
public T MyGetInstanceOfType<T>()
```

Here the compiler knows the type every time a caller uses this method.  It can guarantee the method's return, because it knows the type on all of the calls.

Answer (score 2):

With `var list = new List<MyClass>();` the List class is told at compile-time that it is tied to a specific type.  The compiler can then do type checking to ensure that only elements of MyClass are added to the list.

With `var pe = Expression.ParameterExpression(typeof(MyClass), "myinstance");` the expression is told at runtime what type of parameter it is working with.  The compiler is unable to do strong type checking with this approach.  It is better for dynamic code where things can't be determined at compile time but those cases are rare (though expression trees are one of them).

Answer (score 0):

Technically, a generic version could be easily created since it could call the overload that takes a type like:

```
public static ParameterExpression Parameter<T>(string name) {
    return Parameter(typeof(T), name);
}
```

In this case though, the use of a generic doesn't buy you much. If one of the parameters was of type T or the return value was of type T, then you'd get strong typing based on the specified type parameter.

Adding a generic version of the Parameter method doesn't make it any more or less strongly typed.